# How to prevent arrow key selecting behavior in Material UI auto suggest?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react app with Material UI Auto suggest feature. I have an issue which is when I'm typing a name in the auto suggestion box and select a suggested name by down arrow key, It will selected and will change the input fields value to it. **I only need to go through suggested names without selecting it**. If I click on a suggested name or hit Enter, then only it should be selected. I put the Code sandbox example down here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tfgz5

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onChange` method, along with `newValue` you are also passed the the `method` that triggered the change. See the [documentation here](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#inputpropsonchange-required).

This means that you can check so that you only update the state (which is used to determine what value to be shown) when the user types, clicks or presses enter. In other words, we ignore changes that happens due to up- or down-presses.

So your example could be modified (around line 155) to be

```
  const handleChange = name => (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    const shouldUpdateSelectedValue = method === "type" || method === "enter" || method === "click";
    shouldUpdateSelectedValue && setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: newValue,
    });
  };
```

A modified version of you code is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hcmzl

Comment: Thank you. But I need to avoid up and down key behavior in getSuggestedValue() function in here https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#get-suggestion-value-prop

Comment: Sorry, my link to the updated working demo wasn't working earlier.  
I don't understand why do you need to have it in `getSuggestedValue`?  That prop seems to only be responsible for what shows up in the drop-down. My suggestion works though.

Comment: Your suggestion works there, but I have a class component and inside that class component, that "method" thing is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be rude or anything, but it sounds like you're saying I correctly answered your question and fixed the code in your demo. I can't answer a question you didn't ask or fix code you didn't include in your question.  Inside a class component you can't use the "useState" and other React "hooks", but similar logic should be possible using ordinary "this.setState" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an `onBlur()` event handler on the `inputProps` object of your `Autosuggest` component. Here is an example:

```js
// The onBlur event handler method
const handleOnBlur = (name) => (event) => {
    if (suggestions.findIndex((s) => s.label === event.target.value) === -1) {
        setState({ ...state, [name]: "" });
        event.target.value = "";
    }
};
```

```js
<Autosuggest
    {...autosuggestProps}
    inputProps={{
        onChange: handleChange("single"),
        onBlur: handleOnBlur("single") // Add this line
    }}
...


<Autosuggest
    {...autosuggestProps}
    inputProps={{
        onChange: handleChange("popper"),
        onBlur: handleOnBlur("popper") // Add this line
    }}
...
```

FInd a modified version of your code on this code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4qidj?file=/demo.js